# how do you access a static variable of an object in java?

Tags: java, eclipse

I am working on a program where i have to include two static variables. I included them in my constructor before creating an array of ten objects. Later on, I tried to implement one of the static variables in the following way:

```
if (finalScore >= students.get(0).minA){
            finalLetterGrade = "A";
            aCounter++;
//(student.get(0).minA = 90)
```

The program shouldve worked fine, however Ecipse isn't allowing me to save the program because of the following error message:
"The static field ClassGrade.minA should be accessed in a 
     static way"
The error pops up at the first line of the code that i provided. Could anyone explain to me the correct way to supposedly access a static variable of an object in java, or at the very least advise me on how to get past this error message and save\run my program?

Comment: If `minA` is the static field, the warning wants you to change `students.get(0).minA` to `ClassGrade.minA` . By the way, it's just a warning: it doesn't stop you saving your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get the *warning* because **static** methods should be accessed via their container class itself (`Classname.staticMethod()`), not by one of its instances. Change

```
if (finalScore >= students.get(0).minA)
```

to

```
if (finalScore >= ClassGrade.minA)
```

Comment: How come accessing a static field via instance of a class doesn't work directly (java: cannot find symbol), it only works if the instance is called via a method (e.g. myBike.nrOfWheels doesn't work, but myPerson.getBike().nrOfWheels works...? (with warning but it works))

Answer (score 1):

**static** means that you have only one of that variable / method for the entire class. You can create an infinite amount of objects, but the value won't change. Therefore, you should access it through the class and not an instance of the class:
`ClassGrade.minA` instead of `students.get(0).minA`

Answer (score 1):

Just for your understanding would like to explain the context where static variables can/cannot be used.

Lets say we have a class Demo.

```
public class Demo {

  int number;
  static int counter;

  public static void printCounter(){
    System.out.println(number); // Shows compilation error.
    System.out.println(counter);
  }

  public void printNumber(){
    System.out.println(number);
    System.out.println(counter);
  }
}
```

Now this class has a static variable `counter` and member variable `number`. Similarly it has 2 methods static method `printCounter()` and non-static method `printNumber()`

Now let's go by the definition

**Member variable** : variable belonging to a particular object

**Static variable** : variable belonging to a particular class. This means       every object of that class can access that variable. Therefore variable belonging to all the objects.

Let's consider `printNumber()` method first. You will invoke this method through an object of Demo class like `Demo demo = new Demo()`. This method can access a member variable which belongs to that object. It can also access static variable because a static variable belongs to all the objects. Therefore static variables can be accessed inside member-functions.

Now lets consider `printCounter()` method. You will access this method through class like `Demo.printCounter()`. Now imagine we had earlier created 3 Demo objects and the value of `number` is different for each object. So if I try to access `number` in printCounter() method, which value will it access? None. Because there are multiple values. Hence member variables can't be accessed from static functions and it shows compilation error.